# invokeOnCompletionHandler cause is null despite the exception

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

I'm handling the exception within the `CoroutineExceptionHandler`

It's a bit of contradiction, variables in the debugger are not null, showing a cause and message but the code behaves as if cause is null and navigates away.

I have attached the debugger screenshot

As per the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-job/invoke-on-completion.html)

> > Cause is null when the job has completed normally.

```
lifecycleScope.launch(CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, e ->
    println(e) // works
}) {
    val user = viewModel.findById(userId) // throws an exception
}.invokeOnCompletion {
    if (it?.cause == null) // debug breakpoint shows the cause not null
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_userForm_to_userList) // this still executes
}
```

---

**Screenshot**

first two watches clearly demonstrates `cause` as null but then the 4th watch `it` is not null.

[image]

Comment: Not sure I am correct or not so just leave a comment here. I believe you watched `it?.cause` before `invokeOnCompletion` callback was calling. At that moment, there was no reference to it so it will return `null`.

Comment: And when `invokeOnCompletion` runs, `it` is initiated there and if an exception occurs, it will be the `exception` object. But this `it` is pointing to a different reference of you watch variable which is null.

Comment: I changed `if (it == null)` instead and working now. maybe the problem is with checking `it?cause` in the if condition